# Were punch-card data-processing systems susceptible to "Bobby Tables"

Tags: punched-cards, security

At least in the U.S., during the 1970s and 1980s (and likely before), many tollways and other ticket-based systems used to use publicly distributed and collected "IBM-style" punched cards along with automated equipment.  When someone entered a toll way, for example, one would receive a punched card which would be handed to an attendant at the exit.  Presumably, the cards could be fed into a computer to, among other things, produce a report of how much different portions of the tollway were used.  If toll collectors kept stacks of cards in order, and placed a "time of day" card onto the stack every hour, such reports could also include information about rush-hour and non-rush-hour usage compared.

Did such systems make any effort to guard against the possibility that a malicious person with a card punch might alter cards so as to not only supply meaningless information, but perhaps disrupt system operations in more serious ways, such as by having a few consecutive motorists at a toll booth submit a JCL control card followed by some cards that were programmed to run malicious code?  Were there ever any incidents of them being attacked in such a fashion?  Or were the set of people with the knowledge that would be needed to perform such an attack and the set of people who would want to carry out such an attack sufficiently disjoint that no such attacks were ever attempted?

Comment: As I recall it, the card was read at the exiting toll booth to get the amount owed (and perhaps compared with the printed entrance), meaning an error would be generated at that time (and the toll based on the printed info). I figured it was more a check on the honesty of the toll taker so the cash drawer tally would match the card tally. But I have no clue what was done with the cards beyond my picking one up and handing it over with the toll.

Comment: @JonCuster: If the purpose was simply to trigger the machine at the destination booth, the cards could have been much smaller and wouldn't have had to use the IBM format, though perhaps using a card duplicator was easier than using any other kind of bulk-punching apparatus.  I think some libraries also used such cards to track what books were checked out and when they were due, by having a card in each book with the title on it, and keeping a stack of cards for each day indicating which books would be due on that date.  I'm sure punched cards were used for many other purposes as well.

Comment: As noted, I have no clue what else was done after the toll booth. But the card was inserted in a machine in the booth (and likely had more holes punched in it), so anything invalid in the section read would likely trigger an error condition. Never had that happen to me though. I look forward to an answer to this!

Comment: @JonCuster: Most of the cards I recall were punched somewhere on the right half, but weren't punched anywhere near the left; I would expect that toll booth equipment would look at just enough information to compute a price and ignore anything else.

Comment: https://www.ibm.com/ibm/history/exhibits/specialprod1/specialprod1_8.html has some info.

Comment: @JonCuster: Thanks for the link.  Although tool booths are the place I most often saw such cards, I've also encountered punched cards used for similar purpose in such a wide range of other venues that the phrase "Do not bend, fold, multilate, or spindle" became as much part of the American lexicon as the "This bag is not a toy" warning one finds everywhere today.

Comment: http://www.columbia.edu/cu/computinghistory/650.html talks about the 650. Doesn't look like JCL was a part of it. But by the 70's who knows (although it isn't like the PA Turnpike I was familiar with seemed to roll out snazzy new tech quickly).

Comment: @JonCuster: I don't know what sorts of equipment were used when and by whom, but it wouldn't be hard to imagine that some of the systems that used punch cards would use a general-purpose machine to process stacks of them.  If workers at a plant who are arriving and leaving at the normal time would each take their time card from a rack and drop it into a slot, and those arriving or leaving at other times would be required to do something else to record the time, taking the stack of cards and feeding it to a machine that was running a payroll program would seem like a practical way to do things.

Comment: "Little Bobby Tables" happens because user data is inserted into code that is then interpreted.  I'm thinking that was anywhere from uncommon to exceedingly rare in mainframes of the punched-card era, but I look forward to knowledgeable answers from those who were there.

Comment: @WayneConrad: In the late 1970s when I first wrote FORTRAN, the computer the university used for FORTRAN (or, I think, PL/I) received submitted via punched cards.  From what I understand, everyone's  cards were inserted as a batch, but the system would look for certain cards to separate different students' programs.  If someone submitted a stack of cards with an end-of-batch and JCL card in the middle, it would get processed as two separate jobs.  The JCL cards that we were using would result in a banner page being printed with rows of asterisks on the perforations along with...

Comment: ...the student's ID number, but I don't know if the system was hard-coded to always generate such pages with every job, or if it only did so because it was instructed by the JCL.  If a job was submitted that used, as data, a stack of cards to which the public had access, someone who could tamper with those cards would have been able to run arbitrary code on the machine.

Comment: @supercat A clever hack to be sure!  I'd vote that up as an answer.

Comment: @WayneConrad: What part is the "clever hack"?  I was merely describing how the university computer facility was run, which I would expect was probably typical of how many such facilities were run.  Perhaps I should edit that into the question to make clearer the security vulnerability I'm wondering about?

Comment: No, because punch cards didn’t use SQL.

Comment: @user3840170: No, but on at least some punch-card based systems, the cards for different jobs were separated by "job control cards" which had hole patterns that shouldn't appear on data cards.  If someone could introduce into a stack of data cards that were used on such a system, a sequence of altered cards that contained job-control hole patterns along with some malicious code, that person could run code of their choosing on that system.